# DNS error with sbs2003 migration to 2011

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011

I have been getting that message `Your Local server is not in the name server records` and it is not going away. I have followed the suggestions from [this](http://blog.ronnypot.nl/?p=879). Other suggestions are also same as his anyway. But the error is not going away. Anything I can do or check log? Could anyone point me to right direction?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. Have you used the updated Migration Tool? Just making sure you have the latest version.
2. Did you go through the 'updated' link from that blog post you referenced?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/10/20/an-update-for-the-windows-small-business-server-2011-standard-migration-preparation-tool-is-available.aspx

This blog post addresses the exact issue. I just want to make sure you've tried everything basic before we dive deeper.